# Why does git pull without arguments produce different results than git pull origin <branch name> where <branch name> is the current active branch?

Tags: git

My understanding from the [git pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) is that

```
$ git pull
```

and

```
$ git pull origin master
```

should produce the same results, assuming the current branch is master. However, in the former case I pull down one object while in the latter I pull down many more (over 100 today). Clearly these two commands are not synonymous, so which is the correct form for just making sure I have the latest copy of master before I base a new ticket branch off of it? Thanks.

Comment: `git pull` is the most overrated Git command. Don't pull, do `git fetch` then rebase your current branch on top of `origin/master`.

Comment: Both are correct, but `git pull` without any arguments will fetch and merge the remote tracking branch.

Comment: The different behaviors are described here, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_configured_remote_tracking_branches. As to why, I think it's just designed this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this is just overall poor design in the original `git pull`, which now has to be preserved for backwards compatibility.

The thing to know here is that `git pull` means:<sup>1</sup>

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command.

You (usually) have your choice of second Git command: rebase, or merge.  You have to decide which one you'll use *before* you see what `git fetch` fetches, which I consider a fairly major flaw and a reason to avoid `git pull`.<sup>2</sup>  You also have some choice of what arguments, if any, `git pull` passes to the `git fetch` step:

- If you specify a remote (`origin`) and branch-name (`master`, in `git pull origin master`), `git pull` runs `git fetch origin master`.
- If you *don't* specify both a remote and branch-name, `git pull` looks at `branch.branch.remote` and `branch.branch.merge`, where *`branch`* is your current branch.  These must both be set (and you must be on some branch at this point as well so that *`branch`* makes sense).  Git then passes the given remote name, from the first setting.

We must then go over to [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) to see what it *does* with the *`remote`* and—if present—branch name or *`refspec`* arguments.  The *`remote`* is straightforward: it sets where the URL comes from, for instance; if the `remote` is origin, your Git looks up the result of `git config --get remote.origin.url` to know how to contact the other Git.

The *refspec* argument is where things get very squirrelly:

- A fetch with *no* refspec argument uses the defaults, from `remote.remote.fetch`.  The standard one for `origin` is `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This *refspec* means *obtain all the commits found by all of their branches, renaming those to my remote-tracking `origin/*` names*.  You can, however, have a *single-branch clone* or some other highly unusual configuration, where something different happens.
- A fetch *with* a refspec argument causes Git to look for names that match the refspec.  Here, things are *complicated*.  A refspec has a general form in which there is an optional *force flag*, a *source* part, a colon, and a *destination* part.  The source and destination can contain `*` wildcards (with certain restrictions; the exact restrictions depend on your Git version).  They can be *fully qualified* references, beginning with `refs`, or you can let Git do certain matching operations as described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

If we avoid covering all possibilities and just concentrate on using a simple branch name as a refspec, we find that the way `git fetch` deals with this is:

1. It *limits what it will fetch* to any commits and other objects needed to synchronize with the commit to which the given branch name points in the *other* Git.  That is, if *their* Git has name `master` meaning `commit defb9a3...`, your Git will make sure that you have this commit in your repository, plus all the parents needed and any other objects needed, by the time the `git fetch` finishes.  But if their Git has other commits and objects that would be needed to update other remote-tracking names, your Git doesn't pick these up.
2. It then fetches as usual and writes the corresponding information to `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, where `git pull` can see it.
3. In Git version 1.8.2 and later, it opportunistically updates the remote-tracking name (`origin/master` in this case).  It does this by reading through the `remote.origin.fetch` lines from the configuration.  In older versions of Git, step 3 does not occur.

**This is a long-winded, but reasonably precise, way to say that `git fetch origin` fetches *all* their branches by default, but `git fetch origin master` fetches only *their master*.**  There are numerous possible special exceptions to this short version, but they're relatively rare.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the not too distant past, `git pull` was a shell script and you could just read it and see where it ran `git fetch`.  This made things a lot clearer.  Now it's a big hairy C program.  Does it still work exactly the same?  Well, we can hope that bugs get fixed, so, probably not *exactly* the same.  But the overall behavior is supposed to remain.

<sup>2</sup>It's not that you *can't* recover, if `git fetch` fetches something you didn't want to rebase-or-merge-with.  It's that it's *easier to run several commands*, with `git log` inserted in the middle whenever that seems appropriate.  Then there's no *need* to recover from a mini-disaster.

---

#### Which one is better?

This is one of those questions that doesn't have an answer, really.  It's like asking whether chocolate ice cream is a better flavor than strawberry, or whether broccoli or cauliflower is a better vegetable.<sup>3</sup>  They're *different*, and whether one is better *for you*, for *one specific purpose*, depends on both you and the purpose.

We can, however, note that if you let `git fetch` fetch *everything* now, a later `git fetch` will generally have less to fetch.  If you restrict `git fetch` right now to just their `master`, and later you also need commits from their `dev` and have to run `git fetch origin dev`, you might have been better off running a single `git fetch origin` that got everything.

If you plan to make use of *n* remote-tracking names, where *n* > 1, a simple `git fetch` that just gets everything is convenient.

---

<sup>3</sup>It is, however, clear that of all cruciferous vegetables, Brussels sprouts are *the worst*.

Comment: I know it says to avoid using comments for a simple thanks, but based on the level of effort, detail and thought you put into your response, I’m sorry but a thanks is absolutely deserved. I did consult multiple other stack overflow questions and never had it broken down in a way that clicked for me like your explanation did. So, thank you indeed